# What timezone does GMail use for internal IMAP mailstore?

Tags: timezone, gmail, imap

Our experiments have shown that GMail does not use UTC for the internal dates in its mailstore. Anyone know what offset it uses? We've narrowed it to between 3 and 7 hours behind UTC (exclusive), and we could figure it out with further experimentation, but maybe someone knows off-hand. UID SEARCH and the like aren't very accurate if you are assuming UTC and it's not the case. :-)

Further, we're wondering if it's consistent regardless of where you're connecting to gmail in the world.

Update: the first test showed UTC-4 or UTC-5, and a second test I did (sending hourly emails) revealed my account to be UTC-7. We're wondering if it's set when you register depending on your source IP (I also registered an account with a UTC-10 timezone and the internal store was still UTC-7. And changing your account timezone later doesn't change the internal store date an IMAP client sees, wisely, I would think).

Answer (score 3):

I had written a python IMAP lib client and confirmed that the Gmail timezone is UTC-07:00 and I have confirmed it over and over again. So, any search results that you obtain (more precisely the after: startDate and before: endDate query) are shifted by that much amount according to your local timezone. This is because the mailstore uses the local time according to the sender SMTP server, which in case of gmail happens to be at UTC-07:00.

Comment: Thanks - as noted in my update above, we did create accounts in different countries (as in, we created the accounts while physically located in different countries) and the internal store dates were different, definitely not all UTC-7, and apparently shifted according to the offset of the particular connection origin. I'm not sure if it's the case 100% of the time, i.e. what exceptions there may be, but a lot of the time it seems that there is no universal offset in the internal store date.

Comment: Just saw your update above. Actually, server timezone does not depend at all on your local timezone, its only used to do offset time calculations with your respective TZ as reference. Essentially, I am led to believe that Gmail SMTP servers are set up in California (at least for India), but they may choose to have different servers for different locations(Not sure, may be to they might do so to maintain network proximity). In any case, for a given location, the SMTP server time won't change unless the server itself changes.

Comment: Just to clarify -- our tests showed that with our test accounts (created in Seattle, New York, Dublin, Paris, Amsterdam, and Berlin) the internal store date visible through IMAP did correlate with the local time zone where the account was created, at least within an hour. While the accounts were also created with a default user-changeable time zone setting in their preferences, the changing of this time zone through the GMail UI made no difference as to how the internal mail store date was represented through IMAP -- that seems to be fixed and unchangeable once the account was established.